# What happens to nitride-treated carbon steel skillet if overheated?

Tags: equipment, cookware, skillet, carbon-steel, kitchen-safety

I just got a nitrided carbon steel skillet that has a max temp of 450f. This is supposedly the max temp of the treatment, but I can't find anything about what happens if it does overheat. Does it produce toxins? Can the pan be simply reseasoned like reg CS?
Also, can I still use it in oven/broiler at higher than 450f if it's full? (the handle is removable)

Answer (score 1):

[Nitriding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitriding) is not the same as seasoning

> Nitriding is a heat treating process that diffuses nitrogen into the surface of a metal to create a case-hardened surface.

If you exceed the recommended temperature, the nitride in the surface will start diffuse further, loosing the designed effect the longer it is kept at high temperature.

If you want to nitride again the surface, you would need to use dedicated processes, to apply either

- gas nitriding

> In gas nitriding the donor is a nitrogen-rich gas [...] The nitrogen then diffuses onto the surface of the material creating a nitride layer.

- salth bath nitriding

> in salt bath nitriding the nitrogen donating medium is a nitrogen-containing salt such as cyanide salt. The salts used also donate carbon to the workpiece surface making salt bath a nitrocarburizing process.

- plasma nitriding

> n plasma nitriding, the reactivity of the nitriding media is not due to the temperature but to the gas ionized state. In this technique intense electric fields are used to generate ionized molecules of the gas around the surface to be nitrided.

From the description, it is obvious that they are "don't try this at home" processes.

Regarding using it in an oven above 450 F, if it contains liquids the water, until present in liquid state, should mitigate the temperature at around its boiling point.

Comment: Thanks, you've partially answered my question. Let me put it another way.  If I overheat it, is it ruined or can I season it like any other CS pan and still use it?

Comment: @Robert Nitriding is a process that is used to harden the surface of a metal without hardening its interior. This improves scratch resistance without also increasing brittleness. If the nitrides diffuse into the interior of the metal, not only will you lose some of the scratch resistance, you'll also have the increased brittleness that the case hardening was trying to avoid. Seasoning won't help either of those.